# How to fix this design issue in chart js react application

Tags: css, reactjs, chart.js

[image]
How do i set margin bottom between legend labels and the line graph top point

You can utilize the plugins option in Chart.js to extend the functionality and modify the legend labels. This approach allows you to have more control over the chart and easily customize the legend labels. Here's an example of how i try:

```
 const options = {
  responsive: true,
  legend: {
    onClick: () => false,
  },
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      display: true,
      labels: {
        generateLabels: function (chart) {
          // Custom legend callback to modify the labels
          const originalLabels = Chart.defaults.plugins.legend.labels.generateLabels(chart);
          originalLabels.forEach((label) => {
            label.text = "Custom " + label.text; // Add a prefix to each label
            label.padding = 10; // Adjust the padding for each label
            label.font.size = 14; // Adjust the font size for each label
          });
          return originalLabels;
        },
      },
    },
  },

OR This 

   plugins: {
    legend: {
      labels: {
        // Additional legend label options can be set here
        // For example:
        padding: 10, // Adjust the padding between legend items
        font: {
          size: 14, // Adjust the font size of legend labels
        },
      },
    },
  },
```

Can anyone help me , how to fix this issue ?

Comment: Without the code it's hard to say how to fix it, and also by showing what you have tried, more contributors can help you better.

Comment: Please check my code now.

Answer (score 0):

Chart.js doesn't provide any direct property to customize the margin you are talking about. The only thing you can change is the padding, however, only the top padding is impacted concerning the legend.

According to their doc, a good way to setup this margin is to use the custom HTML Legend : [HTML Legend](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/legend/html.html)

This method allow you to give any style input in html elements containing the legend.